# ¿Como crear una barra de desplazamiento?

Tags: java

bueno tengo un problema, tengo 2 metodos uno que cuenta las lineas de un archivo .txt y otro metodo que crea un arreglo del tamaño de las lineas del archivo para asi poder imprimirlo en un JOptionpane.messagedialog

1.er metodo

```
//metodo que devuelve el numero de lineas del archivo case 6
public int mostrarfarmacia(InputStream is) throws IOException{
    int n=0;
    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader bs = new BufferedReader(ir);
    String linea = bs.readLine();
    while(linea!=null) {
        linea = bs.readLine();
        n++;
    }
    bs.close();
    return n;
}
```

2do metodo

```
//metodo que imprime el archivo faramcia case 6
public void mostrarfarmacia1(InputStream is, int n) throws IOException{
    int i = 0;
    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader bs = new BufferedReader(ir);
    String[] lineas = new String[n];
    String linea = bs.readLine();
    while(linea!=null) {
        lineas[i] = linea;
        linea = bs.readLine();
        i++;
    }
    bs.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lineas);
}
```

Mi problema es que al imprimir el array con el contenido del archivo, si el archivo esta largo, al imprimirlo en el JOptionpane.showmessagedialog imprime una parte y lo demas lo imprime pero fuera de la pantalla lo que imposibilita el poder visualizarlo, me gustaria saber si hay una forma de poder visualizarlo todo, o tendria que usar otras funciones que no sea el JOptionpane.showmessagedialog

Comment: Pienso que te podría venir bien un `JTextArea` y un `JScrollPane`. Se muestra un ejemplo de ello en el sitio inglés de Stack Overflow - [JOptionPane and scroll function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375022/joptionpane-and-scroll-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un JOptionPane puedes usar un jlabel para mostrar el texto para marcarle el ancho y largo de la ventana lo puedes hacer con html y css

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    this, 
    "<html><body><p style='width: 200px;'>"+"mensaje a imprimir en la Jlabel"+"</p></body></html>",  // Contenido + Css
    "Este es el título",   // Título
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE // Tipo deJOptionPane
);
```

Si necesitas mas espacio o no te gusta el largo y ancho de la pantalla que ocupa podrás usar un JscrollPane y dentro un Jlabel osealo mismo pero teniendo por encima de la Jlabel el JscrollPane

Mas información sobre html en componentes: [Aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

y aqui un ejemplo de uso de css en Swing: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861724/is-there-a-word-wrap-property-for-jlabel/7861833#7861833)

Adicionalmente si usas java 1.7 o superior te recomiendo usar el try con recursos para que java gestione el tema de cerrar los recursos usados y no tengas que estar usando el .close()